# Varying error messages

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I keep getting varying error messages although I'm not making changes to code, or the pysical testing enviroment. It also apears that the enviroment that I'm testing is completely the same, just from a visual apearance, and I don't see a reason for it to change anyway.

When repeating my test multiple times without any changes to either element I get varying error messages on crash which make it unclear on how to overcome this problem. I'm running my tests using Robot Framework 2.8.7 using Selenium2. The test has also succeeded before aswell on multiple accounts which makes it strange to why it crashing with varying reasons where it hasn't before with the exact same code.

All of the errors are caused by one line of code which is as follows:

```
select from list | name=lstServiceUser | 789456
```

And here is an example of the error messages that frequently appear.

```
KEYWORD: Selenium2Library.Select From List name=lstServiceUser, 789456
Documentation:  
16:15:03.402    INFO    Selecting option(s) '789456' from list 'name=lstServiceUser'.   
16:15:04.338    FAIL    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag_name'


KEYWORD: Selenium2Library.Select From List name=lstServiceUser, 789456
Documentation:  
16:24:51.060    INFO    Selecting option(s) '789456' from list 'name=lstServiceUser'.   
16:24:53.391    FAIL    NoSuchElementException: Message: Finding elements with name == lstServiceUserreturned an unexpected error


KEYWORD: Selenium2Library.Select From List name=lstServiceUser, 789456
Documentation:  
16:27:08.545    INFO    Selecting option(s) '789456' from list 'name=lstServiceUser'.   
16:27:09.742    FAIL    ValueError: Element locator 'name=lstServiceUser' did not match any elements.
```

And like I said, sometimes the test even passes!

If anyone has any suggestions on how to overcome this problem, or to fix it, that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look it sounds to me like sometimes it cannot find what it is looking for as it doesn't exist on the page yet.  I would advise using some form of wait to ensure what you need to use is there before continuing

E.G

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10    2    select from list  name=lstServiceUser  789456
```

The above is a bit crude but hopefully you can get the idea, you can find further information on the keyword here:

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds

There are plenty of other waits to chose from which might serve your use case.  Selenium2Library in particular has plenty.  I had a similar issue recently caused by my version of chrome, it broke a number of tests but using the above methods, we were able to get round it pretty quickly.  Further information on that issue here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1158

Comment: did you have success with this?